# Redirect to specific route on session timeout in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

In the session.php file under Config directory of laravel 5.1, I have specified `'lifetime' => 10` which logout the user after 10 minutes of inactivity. But it does not redirect to login page automatically when the session expires until the user clicks on some link.

I want to redirect the user to the login page instantly after the session expire even if no link is clicked. I also want to get some values in the session before resetting it.

Answer (score 0):

you need use javascript to achieve this,

when the first time you set session,in that page

```
var t_click=0;
var timer= function(){
setTimeout('timer()', 1000);
    t_click += 1;
    if(t_click <= 600){
        window.location.href="the page url you want go and deal with what you want to do";
    }
}
```

above is the javascript after 10 minites will trigger redirect